# UILabel that fills the whole horizontal empty space and goes around another view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm struggling with this problem for some time now and couldn't find any answers.
So, basically, as you can see from the image below the UILabel text gets the entire space. What I want is to go around the UIImageView and overflow only the white space. I tried hugging and priorities but nothing worked.

I would appreciate any help!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic or simple way to do this. You can't use a mere UILabel or any built-in interface object. You would have to draw the text yourself with TextKit and use an exclusion path in the NSTextContainer to make the line fragments wrap around the area where the image goes.

Comment: Thanks, @matt! Your answer pointed me in a direction. I will explore TextKit and already found something similar done in objective-c.
https://www.appcoda.com/intro-text-kit-ios-programming-guide/